# (string)combination Purpose?

Tags: c#, variables, types, combinations

I'm following an exercise which tasks me to...

> "Declare two variables of type string with values "Hello" and "World".
>   Declare a variable of type object. Assign the value obtained of
>   concatenation of the two string variables (add space if necessary) to
>   this variable. Print the variable of type object".

Now here was my original solution:

```
string hi = "Hello";
string wo = "World";
object hiwo = hi + " " + wo;
Console.WriteLine(hiwo);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I found a good website that gives sample solutions of the exercises I am going through, which I have started to go through comparing to my answers, In this one I noticed I was nearly spot on, apart from an extra line. I've modified my original code to illustrate the comparison more easily.

My modified code:

```
string firstWord = "Hello";
string secondWord = "World";
object combination = firstWord + " " + secondWord;
Console.WriteLine(combination);
```

Given Solution:

```
string firstWord = "Hello";
string secondWord = "World";
object combination = firstWord + " " + secondWord;
string a = (string)combination; 
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

I believe understanding this extra line is the purpose of the exercise. So my question is why is the extra line exists and what the benefits are to having it? The section of the book is understanding types and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra line is a [type cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

> A cast is a way of explicitly informing the compiler that you intend to make the conversion and that you are aware that data loss might occur.

Usually, a cast doesn't really return a different object. It just checks if the object is, at runtime, of the type you're casting to. That is, the expression `firstWord + secondWord` returns an *object* of type `string`. Assigning it to a *variable* of type `object` doesn't change the fact it's really a `string`. Similarly, doing `(string) combination` doesn't return a different object – it just tells the compiler that the expression is of type `string`. (If `combination` wasn't really a `string`, the check would fail and throw an exception.)

In this case there is no benefit to having it there I can see. `Console.WriteLine(object)` converts the object to a `string` internally, and an object that is already a `string` will just "convert" to itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution when you call

```
Console.WriteLine(Combination)
```

.ToString() method is called internally. Therefore you don't feel the difference.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.

Whereas in the given solution object is first converted to string and then written.

To understand the difference let's take another example

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
Console.WriteLine(tb);
```

output would be System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: that is the type of object

Answer (score 0):

In your version what is happening in the line `Console.WriteLine` is a call to the virtual `ToString` method, which because of being virtual is in fact executed in its version implemented in the `string` class (which just returns the string).

The given solution explicitly casts the object into string. The difference is thus in increased readability - less things are happening behind the scene - it is made explicit that you're operating on a `string` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The extra line is basic casting the object to a string type in order for it to be printed out.

Another way would be...

```
string firstWord = "hello";
string "secondWord = "world";
object combination = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstWord, secondWord);
Console.WriteLine(combination.ToString());
```